# Not able to run uber fat jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I wanted to create a uber-fat jar for my spring boot app and for that I am using *maven-shade-plugin*.After mvn clean install , i see there are two jar created one is normal and another shaded,normal jar is working fine but when I am trying to run shaded jar it is failing with below error

**Error: Could not find or load main class com.walmart.SpringAppInitializer**

Below is my plugin added in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <start-class>com.walmart.SpringAppInitializer</start-class>
</properties>

<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                             <relocation>
                               <pattern>com.google.gson</pattern>
                  
                 <shadedPattern>com.shaded.google.gson</shadedPattern>
                             </relocation>
    </relocations><shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
```

Can anyone please suggest why fat jar is not working

Comment: Spring Boot already creates an fatjar. Ditch the `maven-shade-plugin` that only interferes with the one that Spring Boot already creates for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I wanted to shade a gson library due to version conflicting issue, how to do that in that case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just fix the conflict? Trying to shade a spring boot jar can (in my experience) lead to interesting things to happen.

Comment: Why do you have a version conflict? Just use the one which is provided by Spring Boot... or change that version via `<gson.version>2.10.1</gson.version>` property... and do not use maven-shade-plugin for packaging that will not work in that way..